# Как вывести ответ только в случае, когда a = 2, и b = 4 при максимальном i?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0, 1000000):
    x = i
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while x > 0:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            a += 1
        else:
            b += x % 10
        x = x // 10
```

Comment: конструкция if вам уже знакома. В чем тогда проблема?

Comment: если в конец добавить "if a == 2 and b == 4: print(a, b, i)", то после 881111 итерации b почему-то меняется на 4, хотя оно не так. Для примера можно убрать первую строку и вбить в x = 998831 и убрать "if a == 2 and b == 4" - выдаст что-то вроде "2 31 998831", хотя при том, как я пытался сделать (с "if a == 2 and b == 4"), выдается наибольшее значение как раз 998831, но указано, что при нем а = 2, а б = 4.

Comment: Добавить в конец чего? В этом коде как минимум три "конца"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

т.е. задача "найти натуральное число такое у которого 2 цифры чётные и сумма нечетных цифр равно 4"

очевидно что нечетные цифры - это или `1, 1, 1, 1` или `1, 3`, таким образом максимально возможное число - это

```
881111
```

а касательно самого вопроса - идите с конца:

```
for i in range(1000000, 0, -1):
    x = i
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while x > 0:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            a += 1
        else:
            b += x % 10
        x = x // 10

    if a == 2 and b == 4:
        print(i)
        break
```

ну или если чуть покороче :)

```
for i in range(1000000, 0, -1):
    a, b, x = 0, 0, i

    while x > 0:
        a, b, x = (a + 1, b, x // 10) if x % 2 == 0 else (a, b + x % 10, x // 10)

    if a == 2 and b == 4:
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Для максимального i надо начинать не с 0, а сразу с конца. Как только а и б достигнут нужных значений, то задача решена.